# How do I get back to the source window in TeXShop?

Tags: texshop

I feel this is a very, very silly question, but when I open a `.tex` file with TeXShop it compiles it immediately, shows the preview, and doesn't show the source code. I've tried to get back to the source code with `CMD-1` but it didn't help. How should I get back to the source?

Comment: The standard way to switch between Preview and Source Windows in TeXShop is Cmd-1. I’m not sure what is happening on your system. Are you using a distributed source (I.e., have a root file which “includes” other files)?

Comment: Wait... do you have TeXShop set up to use an external Editor? Under the Source tab in TeXShop->Preferences do you have `Configure for External Editor` in the Startup section checked?

Comment: @HerbSchulz that was it, thanks! Consider turning your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Not silly at all. I just had to face the same problem. (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have TeXShop set up to use an external Editor? Under the Source tab in TeXShop->Preferences do you have Configure for External Editor in the Startup section checked? If so, uncheck that box, save the preferences and restart TeXShop.